# How to mark ran on all change sets of a changelog using a single pre condition?

Tags: xml, liquibase, postgresql-9.4, preconditions

I am using liquibase v3.6.3 with postgresql v9.4.

I have a changelog file with over 40 change sets. All of these changes (which consists of adding tables, foreign keys, etc.) have a single condition to run, which is to check if a specific table exists (say, `myTable`). If this condition is false, that is `myTable` already exists, I need to mark all changes as executed.

I could do the following on every single change set of the changelog file, which I have already tested and works:

```
<changeSet>
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="myTable" schemaName="public"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    ...my change 1
</changeSet>

<changeSet>
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="myTable" schemaName="public"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    ...my change 2
</changeSet>

...

<changeSet>
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="myTable" schemaName="public"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    ...my change n
</changeSet>
```

The issue is I would need to repeat the pre condition for every single change, and repeated code is hardly a good practice.

I could instead add the following at the beggining of the changelog file:

```
<preConditions onFail="HALT">
    <sqlCheck expectedResult="0"> SELECT COUNT(1) FROM pg_tables WHERE TABLENAME = 'myTable' </sqlCheck>
</preConditions>
```

This blocks the entire changelog file from being executed, which is one of the results I want. But I also need to mark the changes as executed, which the sqlCheck doesn't do.

Is there a way to add the pre condition with `"MARK_RAN"` only once and apply it to the all of the change sets in the changelog file?
I couldn't find anything like this on the [liquibase documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html).

Other types of solutions without pre conditions which also mark the changes as executed are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a bit of a hack, but might be a better hack than adding all the preconditions to your changelog.

Start by running the `updateSQL` command against a clean database. This will generate all the SQL that would be applied to a database to deploy all the changesets. In that SQL file that is generated will be a set of insert statements to the DATABASECHANGELOG table.

Extract all those insert statements into a single file. Call it something like "MarkAllMyTableRelatedAsRan.sql", and then in your first changeset use the `<sqlFile>` tag to run those inserts, using the precondition.

Comment: I'm looking for accomplishing the same as OP. Tried this approach, but Liquibase seems to not reevaluate the contents of DATABASECHANGELOG during an update.
After running `update` I get a duplicate set of change sets in the `DATABASECHANGELOG` table. And the changesets I tried to _bypass_ were applied :(

Comment: I'm no longer with Liquibase the company, it would probably be good to submit your question to the Liquibase forums at https://forum.liquibase.org/